# How to compare generic nodes in a linked list using Comparable?

Tags: java, generics, priority-queue, sortedlist

I am implementing a sorted list using linked lists. My node class looks like this

```
public class Node<E>{
    E elem;
    Node<E> next, previous;
}
```

In the sorted list class I have the add method, where I need to compare generic objects based on their implementation of compareTo() methods, but I get this syntax error
"The method compareTo(E) is undefined for type E". I have tried implemnting the compareTo method in Node, but then I can't call any of object's methods, because E is generic type. 
Here is the non-finished body of add(E elem) method.

```
public void add(E elem) 
{

        Node<E> temp = new Node<E>();
        temp.elem = elem;

        if( isEmpty() ) {           
            temp.next = head;
            head.previous = temp;
            head = temp;
            counter++; 
        }else{
            for(Node<E> cur = head; cur.next != null ; cur= cur.next) {
                **if(temp.elem.comparTo(cur.elem)) {**
                    //do the sort;

                }/*else{
                    cur.previous = temp;
                }*/             
            }
            //else insert at the end

        }
}
```

Here is one of the object implemnting compareTo method

```
public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>{
    public int compareTo(Patient that)
    {
        return (this.getPriority() <= that.getPriority() ? 1 : 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the comparable hint. Now after making these changes, I get this error

"Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>> of the type   
Node<E>" 
at this line
Node<E> temp = new Node<E>();
temp.elem = elem;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bound E to Comparable:

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    E elem;
    Node<E> next, previous;
}
```

It will compile now.

Comment: Hmmm... looks familiar somehow ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your generic `E` must be `E extends Comparable<E>`. This way you will get the access to the `compareTo(E other)` method. However, you will be unable to add elements that are not implementing this interface.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the elements stored in your nodes to be comparable, you can state this using generics:

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    E elem;
    Node<E> next, previous;
}
```

this way it is sure, that every `E` implements the `Comparable` interface, so you can safely call the `compareTo` method.

Comment: Hmmm... looks familiar somehow :)

Comment: Does it mean that the patient class needs to implement Node as an interface?

Comment: It only has to implement the `Comparable<Patient>` interface, which means you have to implement a `compareTo(Patient other)` method.

Comment: No. Patient is the Comparable Node is holding. Patient doesn't have to, and shouldn't, know about Node.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, that's what I am thinking. But now I get Bound mismatch error plus that old method error :(

Comment: Here is the code complaining about bounds mismatch

public void add(E elem, int priority)
 {
  Node<E> temp = new Node<E>();
  temp.elem = elem;

Comment: @Bohemian: You too. And Sorrow deserved a +1 as well, for the " you will be unable to add elements..." thing which is important to mention as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    E elem;
    Node<E> next, previous;
}
```